# high charts graphic not loading graphic turns into text

Tags: php, highcharts

I have the code as below, but it draws the data, does not write it to the graph, writes it to the y-axis, can you help?
I want to get hourly averages of the chart, how do I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2fS0.jpg)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'raspberry', 'raspberry_sistem');

$query = "SELECT voltage, current_A, power_W, timestamp FROM readings";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

$json_data = json_encode($data);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    // Get the data from the PHP file
    var data = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Readings'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Timestamp'
    },
    categories: data.map(function(d) {
      return d.timestamp;
    })
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'voltage'
    },
    opposite: true
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'current_A'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'power_W'
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  series: [{
    name: 'voltage',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 0,
    data: data.map(function(d) {
      return d.voltage;
    })
  }, {
    name: 'current_A',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: data.map(function(d) {
      return d.current_A;
    })
  }, {
    name: 'power_W',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 2,
    data: data.map(function(d) {
      return d.power_W;
    })
  }]
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hello, I have a php code as below, but when I run the php code, the data comes as text on the y-axis of the graph, not the graph. Can you help?

Comment: You have used highcharts tag, but I'm not sure if the problem is about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a code with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: Hi, I added it below, can you take a look?

Comment: You didn't provide an example of the final data format that you get. However, based on your chart config I can tell that you use `xAxis.categories` which is incorrect when you provide timestamp data. In that case, you need to change `xAxis.type` to `datetime`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/th7r6z2b/

Answer (score 0):

```
$
import mysql.connector
import time
import json
import serial
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

def add_data(voltage, current_A, power_W, energy_Wh, frequency_Hz, power_factor, alarm):
    # Connect to the MySQL database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='<user>', password='<password>', host='<host>', database='<database>')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert the data into the database
    sql = "INSERT INTO readings (voltage, current_A, power_W, energy_Wh, frequency_Hz, power_factor, alarm) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (voltage, current_A, power_W, energy_Wh, frequency_Hz, power_factor, alarm)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)

    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()

    # Close the cursor and the connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Connect to the slave
        serial = serial.Serial(
                               port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
                               baudrate=9600,
                               bytesize=8,
                               parity='N',
                               stopbits=1,
                               xonxoff=0
                              )

        master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(serial)
        master.set_timeout(2.0)
        master.set_verbose(True)
        # Changing power alarm value to 100 W 
        # master.execute(1, cst.WRITE_SINGLE_REGISTER, 1, output_value=100)

        while True:
            data = master.execute(1, cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS, 0, 10)

            voltage = data[0] / 10.0
            current_A = (data[1] + (data[2] << 16)) / 1000.0 # [A]
            power_W = (data[3] + (data[4] << 16)) / 10.0 # [W]
            energy_Wh = data[5] + (data[6] << 16) # [Wh]
            frequency_Hz = data[7] / 10.0 # [Hz]
            power_factor = data[8] / 100.0
            alarm = data[9] # 0 = no alarm

            # Add the data to the database
            add_data(voltage, current_A, power_W, energy_Wh, frequency_Hz, power_factor, alarm)

            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exiting pzem script);
$
```

Comment: You will need to explain why your code solves the issue.